# How to get the content of a json output

Tags: php, json, api, file, http-status-codes

I have this json

```
Print_r($send);

    {"status":"INSUFFICIENT_APIBALANCE"}
```

and I have this

```
$send = var_dump(json_decode($send));
```

Now am trying to do this

```
   if ($send->status == "INSUFFICIENT_APIBALANCE"){

     echo "Recharge Now";
}else echo "testing";
```

But am not getting the expected result, please help

Comment: `if ($send->status == "INSUFFICIENT_APIBALANCE"){`

Comment: It was a mistake. the problem still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `var_dump()`:

```php
$send = json_decode($send);
```